# WCS 2.0.1 Not working with ESRI Javascript 3.33

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-js-api, wcs

Trying to implement [ESRI WCSLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/wcslayer-amd.html) Class to work with WCS 2.0.1. This works perfectly with WCS 1.0.0, however, when using WCS 2.0.1 I get the error. I have been testing using Geoserver 2.18 to configure the WCS endpoints.

Getting error in browser as follows:

```
3.33:115 Error: not a valid multipart coverage response
    at WCSLayer.js:189
    at c (3.33:104)
    at e (3.33:104)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (3.33:105)
    at c (3.33:105)
    at e (3.33:104)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (3.33:105)
    at c (3.33:105)
    at e (3.33:104)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (3.33:105) "Error: not a valid multipart coverage response
    at https://js.arcgis.com/3.33/esri/layers/WCSLayer.js:189:109
    at c (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:104:350)
    at e (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:104:139)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:479)
    at c (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:63)
    at e (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:104:139)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:479)
    at c (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:63)
    at e (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:104:139)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:479)"
l @ 3.33:115
(anonymous) @ 3.33:116
filter @ 3.33:72
m @ 3.33:116
3.33:115 Error: not a valid multipart coverage response
    at WCSLayer.js:189
    at c (3.33:104)
    at e (3.33:104)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (3.33:105)
    at c (3.33:105)
    at e (3.33:104)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (3.33:105)
    at c (3.33:105)
    at e (3.33:104)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (3.33:105) "Error: not a valid multipart coverage response
    at https://js.arcgis.com/3.33/esri/layers/WCSLayer.js:189:109
    at c (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:104:350)
    at e (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:104:139)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:479)
    at c (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:63)
    at e (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:104:139)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:479)
    at c (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:63)
    at e (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:104:139)
    at b.Deferred.resolve.callback (https://js.arcgis.com/3.33:105:479)"
```

Any idea what sort of multipart coverage response is expected by the API?

Has anyone used ESRI 3.33 successfully with WCS 2.0.1?